# How to activate mobile phone in Chile?

Tags: cellphones, chile, gsm-mobile

I have been told that recently Chile decided to block the IMEI of all phones not officially sold in the Chilean market. As a foreigner who bought a prepaid SIM card, it's quite frustrating!

My phone is compatible but the network won't let me in.

How can I activate my phone / add it to the whitelist?

Comment: don't know if this is the place you'll get the right answer but an IMEI block simply means you cannot use that phone in that network/country.

Comment: Not in chile, you may be able to register your IMEI here but it's a bit opaque.

Comment: That's why I said this might not be the right place. In the US the service provider usually takes your IMEI and binds the SIM card to it. Maybe contacting a local service provider would be your best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to check if your device is compatible with the chilean bands. In [this website](http://bnds.cl/) you could check if your phone is compatible with most of the chilean telcos, but essentially it should be compatible with:

- 2G: 850, 900 and 1900 MHz
- 3G: 850, 900, 1700/2100 and 1900 MHz
- 4G: 700, 1700/2100 and 2600 MHz

Then you must to contact one of the [certification companies](http://multibanda.cl/empresas-certificadoras/) that will register your IMEI for free.
Some points to note:

- If you are only considering to use roaming or WiFi, this registration is not needed. This is only required if you plan to get a Chilean SIM card and use GSM services (mobile internet) or make phone calls.
- You can register it for free, but is only one device per year. After that, fees may apply according each company.
- It looks this process could take up 72 hours (24 hours in the best cases) to enable your device in the network, so consider the hassle if you are doing a short trip.
- This process doesn't ensure that your device is going to receive alerts from the chilean emergency communication system ([SAE](http://www.sae.gob.cl/)).

Comment: Thanks ! I tried Telefónica Móviles with no luck, DEKRA is a better choice ;)